# PySNMP and NetSNMP

Tags: python

Есть два модуля [PySNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/) и [NetSNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Python_Bindings).

Производительность  PySNMP намного ниже, чем у NetSNMP, кто может пояснить? И второй вопрос, что значит в PySNMP асинхронные и синхронные приложения.

```
import time
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

def cli():
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex,varBindTable =   
    cmdgen.CommandGenerator().nextCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('None','1'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('ats1',161)),(1,3,6,1,2,1,17,7,1,2,2,1,2))

start = time.time()
cli()
print "!!!Elapsed Time: %.4f" %(time.time() - start)

res = !!!Elapsed Time: 15.7561

import netsnmp
import time

def getmac():
    oid = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))
    res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version = 1, DestHost='ats1',   Community='1')

start = time.time()
getmac()
print "!!!Elapsed Time: %.4f" %(time.time() - start)

res = !!!Elapsed Time: 5.6186
```

Answer (score 1):

Асинхронные приложения нужны, если необходимо выполнить большое количество запросов, эти запросы будут выполняться параллельно, что гораздо быстрее, чем последовательные запросы синхронного приложения. Но всё равно асинхронный PySNMP, медленней чем netsnmp с использованием потоков.